# Google Sheets | Query doesn't bring all the data

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I have a sheet that contains all orders from an eCommerce site.
I made a new tab within that sheet to only bring the necessary columns to process orders (name, address, sku...).

The query is this: `=QUERY(raw_data!A:GM, "select AY, AT, EX, EZ where FB contains 'Product's Name' and AT=''",0)`

The issue is that when the ZIP code starts with 0 or a letter, it is not imported and its cell remains empty.

[Photo Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLgBC.jpg)

I believe the issue comes from the columns having multiple types of data (numbers, strings).

How can I solve this to bring all types of ZIP codes?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Can you share a copy of the spreadsheet with dummy data? Also, have you considered using the solution of changing the format of the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

Query does indeed have issues with mixed data types. One way to solve that is to convert everything to text..

```
=QUERY(INDEX(raw_data!A:GM&""), ..
```

As a consequence of that, you'll have to use numeric column references:

```
=QUERY(INDEX(raw_data!A:GM&""), "Select Col51, Col46 ..."
```

Hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to format the column(s) as text

[image]

In this example, the first column is not formatted and drops the leading zero, col B is formatted as text

[image]